# How to save the output as image file mutliple times with incremental number sequence in the name (name01,name02,etc.)?

Tags: python, image, loops, save, png

I've got a script that output a slightly different image each time it's run. Now I've tried to run it multiple times using **for loops** or **range** and **xrange** functions wihtout success. My goal is to save the image file N times (for example 25 times) with an incremental number attached to the name (for example "filename01.png, filename02.png, etc. until filename025.png).
(please note that I've removed from the code any previous attempt using the above functions in order to not mess up the working script)
Here's the code:

```
from math import floor
from PIL import Image
from random import randint

# Read all images
bckgnd = Image.open('background2.png').convert('RGBA')
orangedot = Image.open('orangedot.png')
whiteX = Image.open('whiteX.png')

# Width and height of each "tile"
w, h = bckgnd.size

# Calculate number of tiles for x and y direction by A4 paper size
# (21 cm x 29.7 cm), and some resolution like dpi = 300
n_tiles = (floor((21.0 / 2.54 * 300) / w), floor((29.7 / 2.54 * 300) / h))

# Prepare final image of sufficient size
final_img = Image.new('RGBA', (n_tiles[0] * w, n_tiles[1] * h), color=(0, 0, 0, 0))

# Iterate all tiles
for i_x in range(n_tiles[0]):
    for i_y in range(n_tiles[1]):

        # Upper left (x, y) coordinates of current tile
        x, y = i_x * w, i_y * h

        # 1st: Paste background to current tile
        final_img.paste(bckgnd, (x, y), mask=bckgnd)

        # 2nd: Randomly generate location of orange dot and paste to current tile
        od_x, od_y = randint(30, 170), randint(0, 100)
        final_img.paste(orangedot, (x + od_x, y + od_y), mask=orangedot)

        # 3rd: Paste white X to current tile
        final_img.paste(whiteX, (x, y), mask=whiteX)

# Save and show final image
final_img.save('final_img.png')
final_img.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work, you have to enter the number of images you want want, and it will save the images as **"filename01,filename02...."**. There was just a requirement of a **for loop**, **counter** and **string formatting**.

```
from math import floor
from PIL import Image
from random import randint

# Read all images
c=1
times = int(input("How many times to save"))
for i in range(times):
  bckgnd = Image.open('background2.png').convert('RGBA')
  orangedot = Image.open('orangedot.png')
  whiteX = Image.open('whiteX.png')

  # Width and height of each "tile"
  w, h = bckgnd.size

  # Calculate number of tiles for x and y direction by A4 paper size
  # (21 cm x 29.7 cm), and some resolution like dpi = 300
  n_tiles = (floor((21.0 / 2.54 * 300) / w), floor((29.7 / 2.54 * 300) / h))

  # Prepare final image of sufficient size
  final_img = Image.new('RGBA', (n_tiles[0] * w, n_tiles[1] * h), color=(0, 0, 0, 0))

  # Iterate all tiles
  for i_x in range(n_tiles[0]):
      for i_y in range(n_tiles[1]):

          # Upper left (x, y) coordinates of current tile
          x, y = i_x * w, i_y * h

          # 1st: Paste background to current tile
          final_img.paste(bckgnd, (x, y), mask=bckgnd)

          # 2nd: Randomly generate location of orange dot and paste to current tile
          od_x, od_y = randint(30, 170), randint(0, 100)
          final_img.paste(orangedot, (x + od_x, y + od_y), mask=orangedot)

          # 3rd: Paste white X to current tile
          final_img.paste(whiteX, (x, y), mask=whiteX)

  # Save and show final image
  img_name = 'filename0{0}.png'.format(c)
  c+=1
  final_img.save(img_name)
```

Comment: Wonderful! You have made my day!! Every time I get stuck and then I realize how simple and at the same time effective the solution was! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

'enumerate' would be good.

```
for ind_x, i_x in enumerate(range(n_tiles[0])):
    for ind_y, i_y in enumerate(range(n_tiles[1])):

        # Upper left (x, y) coordinates of current tile
        x, y = i_x * w, i_y * h

        # 1st: Paste background to current tile
        final_img.paste(bckgnd, (x, y), mask=bckgnd)

        # 2nd: Randomly generate location of orange dot and paste to current tile
        od_x, od_y = randint(30, 170), randint(0, 100)
        final_img.paste(orangedot, (x + od_x, y + od_y), mask=orangedot)

        # 3rd: Paste white X to current tile
        final_img.paste(whiteX, (x, y), mask=whiteX)

        # save to img file
        final_img.save('final_img' + str(ind_x) + str(ind_y) + '.png')
```